# How to convert mdash into LaTeX markup?

Tags: symbols, html, markup

I am converting HTML markup into LaTeX markup by using `sed` command. I need to convert `&mdash;` into its corresponding LaTeX markup. How can I implement it?

```html
&mdash; into LaTeX markup
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You convert the em dash by using three dashes in a row in the LaTeX file: `---`

Actually, this depends on the font, but for all practical cases, this will work.

Answer (score 7):

`\textemdash` - or, if you have a recent UTF-8 capable TeX engine, you can insert the UTF-8 character. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em-dash#Em_dash). Note that the command will gobble a trailing space unless you add a `{}` to it.